# How to remove internet shortcuts from HTML's input file selection?

Tags: html, reactjs, file

When I make standard HTML file input like so:
`<input type="file" id="pdf" accept="application/pdf" />`
the file selection contains not only PDF files, but also "Internet Shortcut" files. If I choose these I get "Catastrophic failure" error. How can I get rid of this behaviour using html/react?

You can try it yourself in [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-sid-nhkok2?file=/src/App.js)

**EDIT 1:**

I'm also sure it's a Windows problem, but I'm still unable to fix it in html/javascript. [Another description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892595/openfiledialog-always-shows-url-internet-shortcut-files).

Answer (score -1):

I would filter the files server side, because there are tools, such as Live HTTP Headers on Firefox that would allow to upload any file, including a shell. People could hack your site. Do it server site, to be safe.

copied from [How to remove internet shortcuts from HTML's input file selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401048/how-to-remove-internet-shortcuts-from-htmls-input-file-selection) with thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283825/alexandre-hitchcox

Comment: Your link refers to this question. Also: i will filter the files server side, but the problem i want to solve is, that i dont want users that are supposed to choose PDF file to see things like game shortcuts in middle of their PDF folder selection - and get fatal error. Go ahed to my Codesandbox link and try to choose any game shortcut to see what i mean.